# ClassNotFoundException: junit.framework.TestCase cannot be found by org.eclipse.xtext.junit_2.4.3.v201309030823

Tags: java, eclipse, junit4, xtext

I'm puzzled by this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/TestCase
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClassHoldingLock(ClasspathManager.java:638)
...
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.RemotePluginTestRunner.main(RemotePluginTestRunner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.CoreTestApplication.run(CoreTestApplication.java:23)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.framework.TestCase cannot be found by org.eclipse.xtext.junit_2.4.3.v201309030823
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 78 more
```

The exception happens when I run the tests for my Xtext DSL as plugin tests (i.e. when a new Eclipse platform is started internally). This happens **before** any of my code is executed.

When I look at the plugin dependencies, I can see that `org.junit_4.11.0.v201303080030.jar` is on the classpath and I also see `/.../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.external_libraries/org.junit_4.11.0.v201303080030/junit.jar`

So OSGis should definitely be able to resolve this dependency.

Does Xtext 2.4.3 work with JUnit 4.11 or do I have to downgrade my Eclipse install to JUnit 4.10?

Comment: when does this happen? And also are you on Kepler?

Comment: I've downloaded Eclipse Kelper JEE SR1 (4.3.1). My target platform was built using the Xtext 2.4.3 archived update site and MWE2 2.4.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two points

**First**

Check your `Project Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries (tab)`. JUnit should be there although this usually will show up in the build.

Check you Project's `Run Configurations->JUnit->Classpath (tab`). JUnit should be under User Entries for your project.

**Second**

Check you have below plugins

```
org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.junit
org.junit (3.8.2)
org.junit (4.8.2)
```

**[EDIT]** This got me on the right track. To fix the error make sure you have org.junit 3.8 in the [target platform](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/concepts/target.htm)!

Explanation: The error above means that Eclipse itself couldn't start. It seems that the JUnit runner has a dependency on JUnit 3.8. It won't be used but without it, the whole platform can't be initialized.

You can see whether you have the same problem by looking at the stack trace: Does it contain `RemotePluginTestRunner.main`?

To fix the error, add the org.junit 3.8 bundle to your target platform.

Comment: I'm using JUnit 4. The libraries tab lists two JUnit JARs. Once org.junit_4.11.0.*.jar from my target platform and once `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/.external_libraries/org.junit_4.11.0.v201303080030/junit.jar`. I think the latter is added my the JUnit Plugin Test launcher.

Comment: Plugins Tests don't have a Classpath tab in `Run Configurations`. But I checked the Plug-ins tab. In there, I only saw `org.eclipse.jdt.junit.runtime_3.4.400.v20130514-0733.jar` from my target platform. I manually added `org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime_1.1.300.v20130514-0733.jar` but the error is still the same :-(

Comment: You were correct. Despite the fact that `org.eclipse.xtext.junit4` imports `org.junit 4.5.0`, `org.eclipse.xtext.junit` (note the missing "4" at the end) seems to have a dependency to JUnit 3.8. After adding the old, outdated JUnit bundle, the plugin tests started.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class with below code in your project-

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;


public class TestJunitLib {

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
}

@Test
public void test() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}

}
```

On saving if eclipse shows compiler errors. Press Ctrl + 1 ( Quick Fix )  and select one of the below-

a) Add jUnit 4 library to buildpath
b) Fix project setup

If a does not appear your eclipse installation is missing jUnit 4 plugin.
In that case google up on how to install jUnit in eclipse.

Comment: this works. My problem is that Eclipse itself wasn't starting when the org.junit 3.8 bundle wasn't in the target platform.

Comment: I'm trying to run an Eclipse JUnit Plugin test. See my edits to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may have have unresolved issues in your pom.xml file. Open the problems view solve accordingly. Then ideally you will be able to run the test cases successfully without encountering the classnotfoundexception.

Comment: As I explained in the accepted answer, this isn't about Maven. The error happens when Eclipse itself is started. hence there is nothing in the problems view.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible places to check for more details:

1. Decompile the jar you mentioned (`jar tvf` or `javap -classpath` and specify the JAR), and check for its dependecies
2. Check `eclipse.ini` for some initialization variables that could possibly be fixed.