# Eclipse Plug-in Test execution for JUnit4

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I have a `JUnit4` test suite and I want to execute it under the `JUnit Plug-in Test` run configuration.
[image]

It passes successfully when running through the `JUnit Test` configuration, but for plug-in conf it fails in different ways.

For example if I use `JUnit4TestAdapter` it fails with `ClassCastException`, and if I trying to run it only through the `@RunWith` annotation it wrotes "No methods found" error. For both implementations I use `JUnit4` Test Runner setting inside run configuration.

I use

- Eclipse Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)
- Jdk 1.8
- linking JUnit 4.1 lib to the plugin.

For first case it seems that Eclipse proceed to use the JUnit3 version when executing the suite.
Here it is:

```java
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ DndTest.class })
public class JSTestSuite {

    public static Test suite() {
        return new JUnit4TestAdapter(JSTestSuite.class);
    }
}
```

And exception is:

```java
java.lang.ClassCastException: junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter cannot be cast to junit.framework.Test
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.getTest(RemoteTestRunner.java:403)
```

While starting the test I have a strange log message in console:

```java
!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 2017-05-04 17:58:57.279
!MESSAGE Could not install bundle ../../platform/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime_1.1.600.v20160505-0715.jar   No match is available for the required execution environment: J2SE-1.5
```

I see this lib is on the place, but I can't understand why it failing to be loaded. For `JUnit3` Test Runner setting junit3 lib is loaded ok.
There are some bugs related to such issues (like [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=165013)) but it is really hard to understand what can I do in this case.

For second case I just try to execute simple `JUnit4` case without using the `JUnit4TestAdapter`, but it can't find any methods.

Reloading of eclipse and renaming of the methods didn't help.
What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 3):

I found that there are couple of issues. First I consider one by one to solve the issue.

> **Issue#1:** No match is available for the required execution environment: J2SE-1.5
>
> **Issue#2:** java.lang.ClassCastException: junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter cannot be cast to
>   junit.framework.Test

### Solution for Issue#1:

### First solution:

1. Right-click on your project
2. Click Properties
3. Click the "Java Compiler" option on the left menu
4. Under JDK compliance section on the right, change it to "1.8"

### Second solution:

If you use maven in your project, then you can change pom.xml file as below:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

**Resource Link:** [Maven "build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.5", even though I changed it to 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804945/maven-build-path-specifies-execution-environment-j2se-1-5-even-though-i-chang)

### Solution for Issue#2:

JUnit runner has a dependency on JUnit 3.8. It won't be used but without it, the whole platform can't be initialized.
So you need 2 versions like the following

Check you have below plugins

```
org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.junit
org.junit (3.8.2)
org.junit (4.8.2)
```

### How to check for JUnit?

In eclipse, please check in 2 sections.

1. Check your Project `Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries (tab)`
2. Check you Project's `Run Configurations->JUnit->Classpath (tab)`

### How to fix?

To fix the error make sure you have org.junit 3.8 in the [target platform](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/concepts/target.htm)!

All credit goes to [A Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2325987/a-paul).

### Resource Link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21334162/2293534

[Aaron Digulla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34088/aaron-digulla) has commented like below:

> Despite the fact that org.eclipse.xtext.junit4 imports org.junit
>   4.5.0, org.eclipse.xtext.junit (note the missing "4" at the end) seems to have a dependency to JUnit 3.8. After adding the old, outdated
>   JUnit bundle, the plugin tests started.

Comment: Hi, @SkyWalker. Thanks for the great answer, but it didn't help. 

First issue was not resolved by the provided steps, because our project is already configured to use jre 1.8. And we do not use maven.

The second scenario you provided is about how to run tests under the JUnit configuration, but for now it is working ok (tests pass). I'm looking for the solution to run them under "JUnit Plug-in Test" configuration. JUnit 3 library is located inside target platform and junit4 lib is linked to the plugin itself. And also there is no Classpath tab under the "JUnitPlug-in Tests" conf.